# how to use np.ix_ for submatrices

Tags: numpy-slicing

I have a 3D array in numpy of shape (4, 13, 13) where each of the 4 rows is a submatrix of 13x13.

How do I use np.ix_ to index subarrays across all rows?

```
a = np.zeros((4,13,13))
to_select = np.ix_([0,2], [0,2])
a[:, to_select] # returns the error below
a[to_select] # works without error, but is not accessing what I want
```

The error returned is "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Is there a way to use to_select for subdimensions or do I need to do a work around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np._ix`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) returns a tuple of arrays for each axis instead of int/bool arrays as the index, hence they can't be used in conjunction with other slicing methods. Here is a workaround by including all of the remaining axes in `to_select`:

```
a = np.zeros((4,13,13))
to_select = np.ix_(range(a.shape[0]), [0,2], [0,2])
print(a[to_select])
```

Output:

```
[[[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]]

[[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]]

[[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]]

[[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]]]
```